# Create a docker image from old linux distro without distro's repository

Tags: docker

I have a bootable iso image (live cd) with Linux system that is pretty old. That distro doesn't have remote repo (all installations are done from cdrom and separate disk with packages). I wanted to turn it into a docker image. Reading through articles google gave me, I've found several ways to do that. The first one is to mount the iso and find `filesystem.squashfs` - only modern distros use that way, not my case. My distro doesn't have that file available. The second approach is to call `debootstrap` but it requires to specify the repo for the distro with `dist` directory available in it. My distro doesn't have a public repo. What can I do? Is it even possible? I think that should be possible by doing a lot of things manually but how?

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problems when I had to containerize an old build server (building natively for legacy systems), eventually I succeeded. This approach describes how to containerize some old Linux distro (kernel 2.6.27 in my case), in the present Linux kernel 5 era.

**General steps**

1. if necessary: boot the old OS (or Live CD image)
2. login to the old system as root (or use sudo)
3. create a tarball from the relevant folders present in root

   ```
   cd / ; tar cfvz image.tar.gz --one-file-system --exclude=/var/log --exclude=/image.tar.gz /
   ```

   - the selection worked in my case; review for yourself which folders to include or exclude
4. transfer the tarball to the Docker host (step not shown here)
5. and import it:

   ```
   docker import image.tar.gz
   ```

   - the previous command will print out some hash
   - if convenient, tag the imported image:

     ```
     docker tag <import-hash> <your-label>
     ```

**Legacy problem: unsupported system calls**

The imported image contains a Linux distribution snapshot. Some binaries can be executed from Docker, eg.:

```
docker run --rm <your-label> bin/ls
```

may actually work.

Some important binaries initially *did not work* for me, most notably bash:

```
docker run -it --rm <your-label> bin/bash
```

was failing silently. (Also, running with `strace` was possible but gave no clear indication.)

As @hiranchaudhuri pointed out, this is likely due to an API discrepancy between the host's kernel and the container's user space code.

In my case the problem was solved by enabling the legacy `vsyscall` kernel API

- for Windows WSL2, this is described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config
- for native Linux systems of today, I guess this can be set in the boot configuration, with the kernel command-line parameter `vsyscall=emulate`, if the present kernel supports this option

Comment: Very likely you are running the wrong kernel/glibc combination. The kernel is the host's kernel, the glibc is the one from the old distro. See my response. You could try to install a current glibc and hope it works after that.

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri I agree, in general you are right, new kernels may break support for old user space code (including libc); there is a bit of gray zone; I'll modify my answer a bit to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt you will succeed on that.
Be aware Docker is not a full virtualization like KVM or VirtualBox. The lightweight virtualization benefits from the docker containers running on the host's Linux kernel. Which means the kernel is the same inside and outside of the container.

If you now try to install some old distro inside the container you may end up with an incompatible combination. Patching the kernel may involve upgrading glibc, and patching that may involve recompiling the rest of the OS.

I am not sure why you want to stick to the old distro, but seriously I believe you are better off with real virtualization.